# Update json value in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I Need to update the JSON value in MongoDB.

```
{
  INR: 71.7406004869,
  BRL: 4.1883509152,
  RUB: 63.6918221982,
  HRK: 6.7076909206,
  TRY: 5.6890271391,
  CNY: 7.0266883058,
  NOK: 9.1081056713,
  NZD: 1.5543233252,
  ZAR: 14.6645929132,
  USD: 1,
  MXN: 19.4436029213,
}
```

My-schema :

```
{
id : 1
name: US Dollar
code:USD
rate:1
},
{
id : 2
name: Indian rupees
code:INR
rate: 70.018
}
```

How to update multiple documents in the collections where I need to check the **'code'** field and then update **'rate'** field.

Comment: `updateMany()` also helps you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since assuming you are using `mongoose` as the ODM, to update multiple documents from the object [**`Moldel.bulkWrite()`**](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.bulkWrite) api can be used to have a single round trip to db and update the corresponding documents.

```
const rateData = {
  INR: 71.7406004869,
  BRL: 4.1883509152,
  RUB: 63.6918221982,
  HRK: 6.7076909206,
  TRY: 5.6890271391,
  CNY: 7.0266883058,
  NOK: 9.1081056713,
  NZD: 1.5543233252,
  ZAR: 14.6645929132,
  USD: 1,
  MXN: 19.4436029213
};

let bulkOps = [];

Object.keys(rateData).forEach((k, index) => {
  bulkOps.push({
    updateOne: {
      filter: { code: k },
      update: { $set: {rate: rateData[k]} }
    }
  });
});

//Model.bulkWrite returns a promise allows using (then, catch)
Model.bulkWrite(bulkOps)
  .then(result => {
    console.info("Bulk update information::", result);
  })
  .catch(e => {
    console.error("Error at bulk update::", e);
  });
```

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti Could be `updateMany` as well and its supported too with `bulkWrite()` api. With multiple updates in post I assumed updating multiple rates together and not rates values on multiple docs, hence the `updateOne()`. Though OP can make it clear about it & I ll update the answer.

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti Though the edit is completely fine. `mongoose` automatically adds `$set` to the update object. if not explicitly used.